# How many psychics can be compared using n trials

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

I have a bit of a tricky question, which I honestly have no idea how to approach.

The scenario is that I want to compare as many psychics as possible. I am told that I can do a total of 10000 coinflips, which the psychics should try to predict.

From this, I need to know the accuracy of the psychics with a confidence interval of 0.05, which should hold with a probability of 99%. The question is how many psychics I can successfully compare within those constraints.

I've tried looking at the wikipedia article on the binomial proportion confidence interval, which seems to be kind of what, but I can't see how to accommodate the "n psychics to compare" part.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I'm a bit confused, because it seems like there are two questions here. First question I see: "How many psychics can be compared using my 10,000 coinflips?" . Second question I see: "How do I find the best psychic to hire, given my 10,000 possible coinflips?" . I think you need to clarify what exactly you're asking (this might be a bit hard, but at least give it a shot). Maybe you're asking both, but then make it clearly so.

Comment: Hi Vladimir. Thanks for the advice. I tried to clear up the question, hope that helped.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about "confidence interval of 0.05, which should hold with a probability of 99%". Aren't these contradictory things? A confidence interval of 0.05 captures 95% of cases. Could you explain what you mean by "should hold with a probability of 99%"?